# Solve $x^3-1=2y^2$ integer solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

find the equation  integer solution
$$x^3-1=2y^2$$

I have read this proof:[proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642805/mathematical-proof-that-m48-is-not-a-cube-of-an-integer-if-13-does-not-div/2643244#2643244), have simple methods? Because this problem is a Olympiad problem. So maybe have other methods to solve it
since $x>0.y>0$ so
$$(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=2y^2$$ since
$(x-1,x^2+x+1)=1$ or$3$.so

(1):if $x-1=2u^2,x^2+x+1=v^2,y=uv,u>0,v>0$,then wehave
$$(2v)^2=(2x+1)^2+3\Longrightarrow (2v-2x-1)(2v+2x+1)=3$$
then
$$\begin{cases}
2v+2x+1=3\\
2v-2x-1=1
\end{cases},~~\begin{cases}
2v+2x+1=1\\
2v-2x-1=3
\end{cases}$$
this two case has no solution $x>0$

(2): $$x-1=6u^2,x^2+x+1=3v^2,y=3uv,u,v>0$$

then $$(2v)^2-3(4u^2+1)^2=1
$$ it's pell equation, maybe this following I can't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As far as I know, the linked answer is the most standard way to solve this without the full machinary of elliptic curves. This equation (and the technique used) is quite similar to [Fermat's sandwich](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsSandwichTheorem.html) $y^2 = x^3 - 2$. Fermat, however, claimed that he solved it, presumably with "elementary" number theory. Now I could probably also claim that I have a nice elementary solution to your question, but this comment section is too short to type it in.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677422/solve-x22-y3-using-infinite-descent).

Comment: In fact, you can see that $x^2+x+1$ can’t be a square directly, unless $x=0,-1$ since it is between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2,$ with equality to the endpoints only when $x=0,-1.$

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the proof you link, it is easier to pass to $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ right from the start:

If $x$ and $y$ are integers satisfying $x^3-1=2y^2$, then
$$x^3=1+2y^2=(1+y\sqrt{-2})(1-y\sqrt{-2}),$$
where the two factors on the right hand side are coprime because their sum is $2$ and their product is odd. Then because $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a unique factorization domain with trivial unit group it follows that
$$1+y\sqrt{-2}=(a+b\sqrt{-2})^3,$$
for some integers $a$ and $b$. Expanding the right hand side and comparing coefficients then shows that
$$1=a^3-6ab^2=a(a^2-6b^2),$$
which clearly has no integral solutions apart from $(a,b)=(1,0)$, corresponding to $(x,y)=(1,0)$.